Good global/Hybrid optimization packages for python
I'm an engineering masters student and looking for a way to optimize a constrained optimization problem in electromagnetics. At each point a relatively fast FDTD transform (1-2 seconds) is performed to find the FOM. This is obviously a lot slower than analyzing many mathematical solutions. However, I would like for ways to address the problem I'm currently having of local optimizers reaching shallow local minima.
I have about 10-40 parameters in my problem. Usually local optimizers can converge to some kind of solution in 3 to 10 minutes. However, for me time isnt really a concern - as long as its done within say 12 hours - but establishing performance bounds is. I looked into scipy and could only find basinhopping as an adequate solution.
So I'm wondering if there are other packages and algorithms that might be better suited to this task? Thanks
As mentioned, I tried scipy basin hopping and it was alright. The parameter space is quite large (10-40 parameters), but constrained quite significantly with bounds.
I'm expecting convergence to performance bounds. I have one device with known performance bounds and would like adequate convergence to these bounds. local optimizers usually dont cut it as they get stuck on shallow solutions.

Have you tried any comparisons with the other global minimizers in SciPy like shgo, differential_evolution, and dual_annealing? You could also try building a surrogate model to speed up the process of evaluating your model then run that through the global minimizers until you're roughly in the ballpark of the global minimum, then switch to a local minimizer to converge faster. I don't think scipy has anything natively to help with this, but scikit-learn and scikit-optimize are designed around building surrogate models and non-convex global black box minimization.

I would also encourage you to test the other SciPy global algorithms (Dual Annealing can be very good in some instances). SHGO won’t cut it as your parameter space is too large. You can also try AMPGO (my version of Tunnelling) from lmfit, or some of the solvers from NLOpt.

You can try Bayesian Optimization, if you consider each problem evaluation costly. Do you have access to the gradients? Is it a multi-objective problem?

@helloworld922 A surrogate model is a very good idea. Currently I'm using a simulation software to perform FDTD. What would a surrogate model look like? A neural network? But yeah switching is definitely a good idea if I can find a way to make a surrogate. Thanks.

@Infinity77 Thanks. I'll give some of the solvers from nlopt a whirl. I did try stogo but it doesnt work that well. Maybe the clustering hybrid solver from nlopt will work well.

@LMaxime I didnt consider Bayesian optimization. I can look into it. I do have access to the gradients. They are calculated with the adjoint method with some finite approximations though, because it is a shape optimization problem. The gradients are actually somewhat expensive to compute and scale with the parameters. Can be anywhere to as fast as the function evaluation to 10x the function evaluation cost. Its a single objective problem.
